# React-bootstrap modal with changeable content based on where it was clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have several components that contain a single g element and then one parent component containing a single svg then the child g components. How do I create a reusable modal whose content changes depending on which g component was clicked?

```
import React from "react";

class Q2L3 extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <g id="Pie-Circle" transform="translate(39.000000, 51.000000)">
            <path
                className="slice q2_color"
                data-q={2}
                data-l={3}
                fill="#fca95a"
                d="M260,100 L260,50 C370.45695,50 460,139.54305 460,250 L410,250 C410,167.157288 342.842712,100 260,100 Z"
                id="Q2-3"
                fillOpacity="0.665392889"
                onClick={this.showAlert}
            />
        </g>
    )
}

showAlert() {
    alert("Q2L3");
}
}

export default Q2L3;
```

I have several of these components, with different paths. I am trying to create a modal that will change depending on which one is clicked (the modal would replace the alert).

Comment: Could you provide your code example? These two sentences doesnt make much sence.

Comment: hmm, I'm thinking set g component value in state via `this.setState({ g: value })`, then pass props to modal component based on what's in the state.